# Issue with team only tool on roblox studio

Tags: roblox

Well, in Team GUI. when i select a team it will give the tool but not work. Like give gun but not shoot.

```
local taser = false

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    player.TeamColor = BrickColor.new("Electric blue")
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Visible = false
    if player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("Taser") then
        taser = true
    else
        taser = false
    end
    
    if player.Character:FindFirstChild("Taser") then
        taser = true
    else
        taser = false
    end
    if taser == false then
        game.ReplicatedStorage.Taser:Clone().Parent = player.Backpack
    end
end)
```

This is the script used for team only tool

Answer (score 0):

You should use `remoteEvent` to give the tool from the `server` instead of from `localscript`.

Comment: Yeah i add remote event , but it give the model but not working. the scripts are still there. idk what happended